# Deserialising mimekit.MimeMessage Object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, mimekit

I am having some issues deserialising a mimeKit.mimeMessage that I serialised to a JSON string and stored in a redis key-value cache.

I am able to serialise and store the mimeMessage successfully using either json.NET or Jil, however when I go to deserialise, the following error is thrown.

**Thrown by json.NET**

> Unable to find a constructor to use for type MimeKit.Header. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'Headers[0].Offset', line 1, position 22.

I am using the StackExchange.Redis method stringGet to get the serialised object and then passing the RedisValue into Json.Net; code snippet below:

```
RedisValue result = db.StringGet(key);

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();

message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MimeMessage>(result);
```

It is my understanding that a default constructor is always created, which makes this a little hard to get my head around, could the default constructor have been specified as private, and if so why?

I have also checked the format of the returned JSON string and it is correct.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a reason you are serializing and deserializing a MimeMessage to/from JSON? MIME is essentially a serialization format for compound documents, so this doesn't make a lot of sense to me. You could just use message.WriteTo() and MimeMessage.Load() to serialize and deserialize.

Comment: Hey @jstedfast thanks for the reply. I didn't realise mime is serialisation format. Do you recommend writing to a string using the writeTo method? Like I said in my question I want to store the message in a redis key value cache and from what I have read a json string seems to be the preferred method of doing this.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't write to a *string*, you'd write to a *stream*. Messages will often have multiple charsets, especially those from outside of Western Europe / US and so can't really be represented by a single character set (hence not possible to represent them as a string).

Comment: I realize that this is a rather old question, however I need to save them to Mongo and for that I need to convert to string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, to clear something up:

> It is my understanding that a default constructor is always created, which makes this a little hard to get my head around, could the default constructor have been specified as private, and if so why?

That's not true. When you define a class with *no* constructors, a default, no-args constructor is generated for you. If you supply a constructor, this default constructor is no longer generated. In other words, a class may not have a default constructor.

---

With that in mind, the `MimeKit.Header` class provides 6 constructors, none of which take no arguments. Because of this, JSON.NET does not know how to instantiate this class, which is why the exception occurs.

Since you don't have any control over the `MimeKit.Header` class, one way to let JSON.NET know how to construct a `Header` instance is to use a custom converter:

```
public class MimeHeaderConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType,
        object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = serializer.Deserialize<JObject>(reader);

        HeaderId headerId = obj["Id"].ToObject<HeaderId>();

        Header header = new Header(headerId, obj["Value"].ToObject<string>());

        return header;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer,
        object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type t)
    {
        return typeof(Header).IsAssignableFrom(t);
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }
}
```

Here, we're deserializing the `Header` class into a `JObject` first. Then, we're picking the `HeaderId` and `Value` out of that `JObject` in order to create a `Header` instance.

**A note here**: I don't know much about this library. This may not be the best way to instantiate a `Header`, and I could be accidentally discarding some information. I only did some very basic tests.

Once you get past this issue, you'll run into another one having to do with property setters that don't accept `null` values.

Specifically, the `ResentMessageId` and `MimeVersion` properties have logic in the setters that throw `ArgumentException`s if you supply `null`. This is an issue, since those values *can* be null when the `MimeMessage` is instantiated.

One workaround for this would be to create a `ContractResolver` that excludes those properties:

```
public class MimeMessageContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private static HashSet<string> excludedMembers = new HashSet<string>
    {
        "ResentMessageId",
        "MimeVersion"
    };

    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        var baseMembers = base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType);        

        if (typeof(MimeMessage).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)) 
        {
            baseMembers.RemoveAll(m => excludedMembers.Contains(m.Name));
        }

        return baseMembers;
    }
}
```

This way, we're never going to accidentally pass `null` to the setter for one of these properties.

**A note here as well**: I noticed that even when I ignored the `MimeVersion` and `ResentMessageId` they still got set if the headers included a `MimeVersion` and/or `ResentMessageId` header. I'm guessing this is baked into the `MimeMessage` somewhere, but again, I'm not totally familiar with this library.

So to use the classes above (only when deserializing), you'd do this:

```
string someJsonString = "{ ... }";

MimeMessage deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MimeMessage>(
    someJsonString, new JsonSerializerSettings
    { 
        ContractResolver = new MimeMessageContractResolver(),
        Converters = new JsonConverter[] 
        { 
            new MimeHeaderConverter()
        }
    });
```

With some basic tests this seemed to work fine. You may end up running into some more issues in actual use, so no guarantees.

Hopefully this will at least get you started.

Comment: I think you may need `public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }`

Comment: Wow, thank you for putting so much effort into this answer, especially the explanations. It is always beneficial to get an explanation of the issue instead of just a code snippet.